# got empty string from json in android

Tags: java, php, android, json

So when i use postman(google app) to send a post method to my php file on my web server, i got a full respond back with all the correct information. but when i am trying to do the same thing on android, i am getting [] in response everytime.

```
@Override
    protected Profile doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.secretvoice1.com/getData.php");
        Profile returnUser = null;
        try {

            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            Log.d("11111:", httpResponse.toString());
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(result);
            Log.d("222222", result);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            if (jsonObject.length() == 0) {
                returnUser = null;
                Log.d("this:", "here");
            } else {

                //String name = jsonObject.getJSONArray("name");
                //String password = jsonObject.getString("password");
                //String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                returnUser = new Profile(user.name, user.password, user.email);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're sending a valid name and password? Cause I tested here with foo/bar and it returned []

Comment: @PankajNimgade why would you ask for username and password?

Comment: i was trying to check this in postman @HanletEscaño